# Google Sheets macro doesnt execute function (TEXTE)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to automatically place dividends date on a column on google sheets.
It seems that the macro doesn't execute the cell correctly or doesn't know the functions.

When I put the following formula on Google Sheets it works completely fine:

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTE(INDEX(IMPORTHTML("https://dividendhistory.org/payout/O/"; "TABLE"; 2);;2);"YYYY-MM-DD"));"-");;1)
```

Then when i put it in setFormula it gives #ERROR!

```
spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=INDEX(SPLIT(ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTE(INDEX(IMPORTHTML("https://dividendhistory.org/payout/O/"; "TABLE"; 2);;2);"YYYY-MM-DD"));"-");;1)');
```

If i'm maybe missing something elsewhere here is the full macro :

```
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */

function Mymacro() {
  // Select the right sheet / init
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Program'), true);
  var currentCell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();

  // Removes everything
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), sheet.getMaxColumns()).activate();
  currentCell.activateAsCurrentCell();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});

  // Place the curent data
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=INDEX(SPLIT(ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTE(INDEX(IMPORTHTML("https://dividendhistory.org/payout/O/"; "TABLE"; 2);;2);"YYYY-MM-DD"));"-");;1)');

  spreadsheet.getRange('B1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=INDEX(SPLIT(INDEX(IMPORTHTML("https://dividendhistory.org/payout/O/"; "TABLE"; 2);;3);"$");;1)');
};
```

Comment: Have you tried with TEXT?

Comment: @Martín oh yeah i'm just dumb aparently ty tho